# Connection bluetooth master and slave with Android

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, softwareserial, hc-05

I send a date from my android to arduino without problem, but also i want send date from arduino to android later of received the date from android.

I have time trying it, but i can not yet, help me.
My codec of arduino

```
char enter;
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial conect(10,11);

void setup()
{
 pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
 conect.begin(9600);
 digitalWrite(8,LOW);
}

void loop()
{
 if(conect.available()>0)
  {
   enter=conect.read();
   if(entrada=='1')
   {
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
    conect.print("1");
   }
 }
}
```

And in the side from android this is my handler for drive the the date that arrive.

```
 Handler mhandler=new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case CONECTADO:
                //ManejarDatos msjre = new ManejarDatos((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                msjre = new ManejarDatos((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                break;
            case MENSAJELEYENDO:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
                String string = new String(readBuf,0,msg.arg1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

And on my class for read and write i have this

```
private class ManejarDatos extends Thread
{
    private final OutputStream salidadatos;
    private final BluetoothSocket sockk;
    private final InputStream entradadatos;
    public ManejarDatos(BluetoothSocket socke1)
    {
        sockk=socke1;
        OutputStream temporalsalida=null;
        InputStream temporalentrada=null;
        try
        {
            temporalentrada=socke1.getInputStream();
            temporalsalida=socke1.getOutputStream();
        }catch (IOException e){}
        salidadatos=temporalsalida;
        entradadatos=temporalentrada;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        byte[] espera;
        int esperaalmacen;
        while (true) {
            try {
                espera=new byte [1024];
                esperaalmacen=entradadatos.read(espera);
                mhandler.obtainMessage(MENSAJELEYENDO,esperaalmacen,-1,espera)
                        .sendToTarget();
            }catch (IOException e){break;}
        }
    }
    public void escribe(byte[] bytes)
    {
        try {
            salidadatos.write(bytes);
            //handler.obtainMessage(MENSAJE_SALIDA,-1,-1,bytes).sendToTarget();
        }catch (IOException e){
            //Log.e(TAG, "....Error al enviar dato" + e.getMessage() + "...");
        }
    }
    public void cancel()
    {
        try{
            sockk.close();
        }catch (IOException e){}
    }

}
```

When i push button, send a date to arduino, here my codec of button(i send 1 for bluetooth)

```
        Enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String salida="1";
            msjre.escribe(salida.getBytes());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `entrada`? Replace `entrada` with `enter` in your arduino code and try again. Also try this `run()` code instead:

```
public void run()
{
    byte[] espera = new byte[1024];
    int esperaalmacen;
    while (true) {
        try {
            esperaalmacen=entradadatos.read(espera);
            mhandler.obtainMessage(MENSAJELEYENDO,esperaalmacen,-1,espera)
                    .sendToTarget();
        }catch (IOException e){break;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Entrada is from my class Connection(other class), that i did use when i would want connect my device with arduino

Answer (score 0):

First try

if(conect.available()>0)
 { 
enter=conect.read();
if(1) 
{ digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
 conect.print("1"); 
}
 }
 }

If that works,  think about what entreda is and that exactly you're trying to do there.

Comment: Sorry, your idea is the same that i have in my codec :(